# SanDisk Ultra Fit Removable disk recognises but fails to mount partitions

Tags: linux, mount, usb-flash-drive

My usb formatted for that last time. I used rufus to create a bootable windows disk. When the boot failed I tried to open it on a running OS and it failed to mount. Here are the symptoms

- Disk detects brand and size of flash drive.
- Recognises partitions and prompts to open them.
- 30 seconds in to plugging in the "reset high speed log" shows
- 35 seconds in, the first error in red "error -100" shows
- 47 seconds in, the rest of the errors show consecutively and the flash is removed from `lsblk` and any other trace of it being plugged in.

The flash drive is relatively new with 6 months of sparse use.

Here is the associated **dmesg** output of the flash drive activity.

```
[190234.263514] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[190276.917031] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[190276.934403] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583, bcdDevice= 1.00
[190276.934414] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[190276.934419] usb 2-1: Product: Ultra Fit
[190276.934422] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[190276.934424] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 4C530001250424113103
[190276.936486] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[190276.938540] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[190277.954698] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra Fit        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[190277.956320] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 60063744 512-byte logical blocks: (30.8 GB/28.6 GiB)
[190277.957797] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[190277.957800] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[190277.958071] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[190277.987407]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[190277.989468] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[190315.526754] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[190320.863579] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[190321.070140] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[190326.406791] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[190331.740112] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[190331.946791] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[190332.170213] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190332.383702] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190332.590070] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[190332.813459] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190333.026932] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190333.233542] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[190333.286881] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[190333.540221] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190333.750196] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190333.956730] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[190334.180237] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190334.393486] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190334.600036] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[190334.626793] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[190335.556966] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190335.766961] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190335.973424] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[190336.193456] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190336.403673] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190336.610075] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[190336.636803] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: Quick test... Format. If successful, write a file to it. Eject, un/re-plug, remount, see what is actually there. If not that one file, discard & replace the drive.

Comment: Note that it is seen as an "Attached SCSI removable disk". Is that normal for a flash USB drive? Try it with another, perhaps smaller, flash drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't format or do anything on it. What i just realized is that the flash drive goes offline with out me having to do anything on it. It is just a matter of 20 seconds wait. Also i am not trying  to replace the disk or save any kind of data. I am just trying to save the flash drive.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I Dont have small disk quantity flash drives but I tried another functioning flash drive; albeit bigger flash drive; and it also attaches ad a SCSI removable.